# Pass facial recognition data to another python script

Tags: python, opencv, voice-recognition, pyttsx, facial-identification

I am going to start on a python project where I'm making a voice assistant using pyttsx and I'm thinking it would be a cool feature to integrate facial recognition into the assistant. I just wanted to ask that if I make a python script for face recognition (opencv), can I pass the result to the voice assistant so it can spell it out loud?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) install `face_recognition`

```
pip install face_recognition
```

2)load faces using cv2 imread.

```py
import cv2  

#faces that look like obama
obama_face1 = cv2.imread("obama_1.png")  
obama_face2 = cv2.imread("obama_2.png")  

#faces that look like trump
trump_face = cv2.imread("trump.png")
```

3) Create a face encoding. Face recognition will create something called a **face encoding** for a face.

```py
import facial_recognition  

obama_vector1 = face_recognition.face_encodings(obama_face1)[0]
obama_vector2 = face_recognition.face_encodings(obama_face2)[0]

trump_vector1 = face_recognition.face_encodings(trump_face)[0]
```

4) create a similarity function. A similarity function tells us if two face encodings are similar.

```py
import scipy.spatial.distance
def cosine_similarity(u:np.array,b:np.array) -> np.float:
    return scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(u,b)
```

5) run the similarity function between faces

```py
trump_X_obama1  = cosine_similarity(obama_vector1, trump_vector)  
trump_X_obama2  = cosine_similarity(obama_vector2, trump_vector)  
obama1_X_obama2 = cosine_similarity(obama_vector1, obama_vector2)
```

6) When you run `cosine_similarity` on two encodings, and the number is small then those two encodings are similar. If the number is large they are less similar.

```py
print("Obama1 is more like Obama2 than it is Trump", obama1_X_obama2 < trump_X_obama1)
```

7) To create something that recognizes you. Save a lot of encodings of yourself. Try encoding other faces as well. Determine what similarity is good enough. The encoding is what you need to determine if you're similar.